# Imageview is not resuming animation when app becomes active

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm animating image view.If I tap the image,it should get flipped and then animation should start. Everything works fine but if app goes background after tapping the image, its not resuming animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
             ImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, -1, 1, 0);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
                ImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 1, 1);

                [_aCardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:index_value]]];

            }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                [_aCardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_back_imageArray objectAtIndex:index_value]]];
                [ImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

                    CGRect frame = [[Frames_array objectAtIndex:index_value]CGRectValue];
                    [self lip_sequence:index_value :frame];
           }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is default behaviour that layer animations removed when the app moved to background. So you need to save animation state and resume it manually.

If you want to do it you need to listen for applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground notifications and handle your animation on it.

You can save you layer or animation on entering background and resume it on getting back to foreground.

To resume animation you can use this example code from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html

Also one good man wraps this task in nice category for CALayer so you can use one-liners:

```
[view.layer MB_setCurrentAnimationsPersistent];
```

To save all layer animation, or

```
view.layer.MB_persistentAnimationKeys = @[@"position"];
```

To save only needed animations.

Comment: It definitely works. I used this approach several times. You can post example project on github or somewhere else if you still interested in help with this.